# Tried everything but Facebook share button won't load the post thumbnail

Tags: images, post-thumbnails, facebook, buttons, social-sharing

Before you say "search google" or "look on this site for similar answers", let me say, I already googled for my problem and read questions like mine.
I already tried everything that I found about to here and on Google to try to solve the problem.
I also tried several things I thought of just in case.

My problem is that my Facebook share button does not pick an image for sharing. It seems to pick the title and the excerpt just well but not the image. Sometimes, in place of the image it will just place a black big or small space before the title, in a side, or above, it depends.
I used to have an image in the server which the FAcebook always took, but I had to delete it since I did not want FB to take that image, now it does not take any img.

Things I tried are:

- Trying other plugins for sharing buttons.
- Disable almost all plugins except for the most neccesary ones which are only 3 or 4, just in case any of them is influencing badly.
- OG plugin witch adds  tags.
- FB Thumb Fixer plugins which also adds  tags
- Adding a fixed image in FB Thumb Fixer options.
- Clearing the cache.
- Using Facebook Debugger, which seem to take the correct image but then in the webpage it does not show it.
- Changing theme to twenty-sixteen and twenty-seventeen.

I think I tried everything I can think and know about. I'm really overwhealmed about this, cause the solution I was given is to remake the whole site again, and I don't even know if that would be an ultimate solution.
What could be the problem? Everything I tried did not work.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I used the googles, and found this link https://davidwalsh.name/facebook-meta-tags which explains that you need to have a `<meta property="og:{tagName}" content="{tagValue}"/>` with the appropriate values to specify the image used when you share a link to FB.

Lots of options in that meta command, and the article explains it quite well.

Since you used various techniques to (probably) change that meta value, check the generated page code to see what those techniques actually added.  You might try looking at the page with a new browser instance (and perhaps using an 'incognito' mode) to see generated code.

Comment: Yes, I checked. OG plugin or FB Thumb Fixer both generate OG meta tags, sorry, not <og> as I said, but meta tags.
The meta tags seem to load the correct image as well, but then it is not shown in the preview before sharing, but the title and excerpt is.
The theme is not made by me, but I'm using a child theme with some changes. So I'll try with another theme, or using only the parent theme.

Comment: that is not an actual answer. referring to some random guys blog instead of official documentation makes it just unreliable

Comment: ... and it is from 2011, which makes it totally prehistoric in terms of FB APIs

Comment: @RickHeliewell Curiously, non plugin worked entirely. Finally I figured out that pernalinks structure affected the way Facebook took the information and I tried out setting different custom permalink structucters and saw that each time information was taken differently in the sharing preview.
I don't like the solution too much.
Basically I hade to use the next structure:
/%year%%monthnum%%day%%hour%%minute%%second%/%author%/%category%/%postname%/ Its abit dirty, but it was the only way to ensure FB was taking big enough images. Cause images have to be big enough BTW, like more than 600x600

Answer (score -1):

og meta is required by facebook,  use this free plugin for wordpress [WPSSO](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpsso/)
once installed and setup use use googles [structured data testing tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) to test the markup.

Hope this helps.

Comment: plugin recommendation is rarely a good answer. If you are going to recomend one, explain how to use it to solve the issue

Comment: You are joking right @MarkKaplun try answering yourself instead of down voting other genuine answers.  The plugin gives instruction and documentation on how to use and its basically add your title and descriptions.  Do us a favour and go and haunt someone else,  Try answering a few questions before hand.

Comment: what the plugin page gives is a lot of text and SEO for whatever it wants to promote. RTFM style texts are not a valid answers here.

Comment: Sorry i'm not into tit for tat arguments and i really don't think this is the place for that.  I gave my answer from past experience and just by installing the plugin will achieve the FB images without any setup.  if you have experience using the suggested plugin then please update the answer as  you seem so willing to do.  Its all yours @MarkKaplun

Comment: @SEODEVS Curiously, non plugin worked entirely. Finally I figured out that pernalinks structure affected the way Facebook took the information and I tried out setting different custom permalink structucters and saw that each time information was taken differently in the sharing preview.
I don't like the solution too much.
Basically I hade to use the next structure:
/%year%%monthnum%%day%%hour%%minute%%second%/%author%/%category%/%postname%/ Its abit dirty, but it was the only way to ensure FB was taking big enough images. Cause images have to be big enough BTW, like more than 600x600

Comment: @SEODEVS and if they are square shaped the better.

Comment: @Lorthas happy you fixed the issue,  I did check the size of your images but they was both the same so I ruled that out.  never thought that the url would have been an issue.  however the solution you have does give dirty url,  I would try to change that.  unless you are creating multiple posts with the same titles or using a multi user or author website I would take out the date and author from the permalinks.  they are just not required.

Comment: @SEODEVS Yes, I know it's dirty but it was trully the only way to fix it. I don't know otherwise how to fix it.
I never read about the URL affecting the Facebook page scraping anywhere, so it's strange. I was asked that images had to appear, and that was the only way. I will have to make a sandbox page for testing other solutions, but I would keep this question open for now.
I hope someone else can through more light into this, cause changing between themes didn't solve the issue neither.